# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window'

Tags: angular, window, postmessage

I'm getting error

```
content-script.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned.
    at Object.t.messageJumpContext (chrome-extension://elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd/build/content-script.js:24:9921)
    at chrome-extension://elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd/build/content-script.js:24:8583
```

I haven't used window.postMessage any where in my code. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this is an issue in Augury Chrome extension

Prevent this extension from working with all sites by right click on the extension icon and select " When You click the extension " option from this can read and change site data sub menu